# How to call a shell file from rubygem command line tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, command-line, rubygems

I have a command that needs to run a shell script. The shell file is in the gem root folder. When I execute the full path, everything is working fine, but can't get the root path.

Running the script from `project_creator.rb`

*I used for testing*

```rb
system("sh /Users/user_name/folder/gem-project/lib/gem/create.sh" + param)
```

**Tried:**

```rb
system("sh ../lib/gem/create.sh" + param)
```

[image]

Comment: If you use an absolute path how do you know it is not working? If you want the stdout and stderr you could try [tty-command](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command).

Comment: @Kris I updated my question. The absolute path was for testing to see that it works.

Comment: When you run it with the relative path, do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I get `sh: ../lib/{gem}/create.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try using something like `File.join(__dir__, '..', 'lib', 'gem', 'create.sh')`.

Comment: Thanks man @Kris, that worked `File.join(__dir__, 'create.sh')`. Can you post an answer? Will accept you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__dir__` to get the directory of the Ruby file. From the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__):

> Returns the canonicalized absolute path of the directory of the file
>   from which this method is called. It means symlinks in the path is
>   resolved. If `__FILE__` is nil, it returns nil. The return value equals
>   to `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`

So in your example you might do something like:

```
script = File.join(__dir__, '..', 'create.sh')
exit_code = system("sh #{script")
```

You can also set the cwd (current working directory) with `system`:

```
system("create.sh", chdir: __dir__)
```

Or:

```
Dir.chdir(__dir__) { system('create.sh') }
```